# Angular2 Exception: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-style

I have done a lot of work with the new Angular2 Framework recently. While testing out some of the features, I ended up with the error:

> `Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known native property`

While investigating the error itself I came to several solutions, like adding the 'directive: [NgStyle]' to the component, but this does not solve the problem.

The code is like following:

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app'

bootstrap(App).then(error => console.log(error));
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Button } from './button';
import { NgStyle } from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><button>Hello World</button>',
    directives: [Button, NgStyle]
})
export class App { }
```

**button.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {NgStyle} from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'button',
    host: {
        '[ngStyle]': 'style()'
    },
    templateUrl: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
    directives: [NgStyle]
})
export class Button {
    style() {
        return {
            'background': 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 66):

That happens when you do not import the [`CommonModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) module. In the recent version of Angular, all DOM level directives are grouped under the same module.

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

You can import [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) or [`NgStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) individually but Angular soon throws an error if you end up using the same in multiple components accessed via router.

Comment: where to import this ? in component or in app.module.ts ?

Comment: import in app.module or in your custom module file like shared.module

Comment: It's lovely when you see an answer which at a glance solves your problem. Thank you.

Comment: It's correct, It happens due to not importing CommonModule

Answer (score 5):

If you need full flexibility, over what host provides

```ts
host: {
  '[class.someName]':'someValue',
  '[style.someProp]':'someValue'
}
```

you need to use imperative ways like

```ts
@Component({ ... }) 
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elementRef:ElementRef) {}
  someMethod() {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.getClassFromSomewhere());
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(
        this.element.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.getColor());
  }
}
```

or other methods [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html) provides.

Comment: Yes i read that too, but i thought it would work with host. This is obviously the prefered method to do what i have explained.

Comment: With that solution in mind. Is it possible to get style information from the host, delivered from the calling component. Like <button [style.background]="red"></button> to override the internal style.

Comment: You can set up `@Input() background` and `host: {'[style.background]':'background'}` to be set like `<my-comp [background]="backgroundFromParent">` or `<my-comp background="green">`

Answer (score 2):

Please note, i have found a solution, while writing this question. And i like to share it, so that other people do not have to search an eternity.

Please take a look at the following link:

> [Angular2 Exception: ngClass within a Host, "isn't a known native property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895703/angular2-exception-ngclass-within-a-host-isnt-a-known-native-property)

As 'Günter Zöchbauer' describes, it is not possible to use directives in host bindings. And he comes with a solution for ngClass.

And here is a simple solution for my problem:

**button.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {NgStyle} from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'button',
    host: {
        '[style]': 'styleAsString()'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/button.html',
    directives: [NgStyle]
})
export class Button {
    styleAsString() {
        let style = {
            background: 'red'
        };

        return JSON.stringify(style).replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace(/"/g, '');
    }
}
```

Note, that this is not a perfect solution because it lacks while 'compiling' the object to plain css. I simply replace all occurences of ' " ' which results in an odd behaviour when using 'url(" "), ...'. 
Hope that i could help somebody with the same or a similar question.

Comment: I like your approach. I reached my vote limit today - will +1 later. Actually I would try to avoid it but I find it interesting that it's working this way.

Comment: Yes, it is a little bit of a hack i think, but it does work. This may be also a good solution if the stylesheet is delivered as plain text loaded from a server or a file. This depends on the Renderer class and its possibilities to add stylesheet that already is plain text.

Comment: Answer is out of date since `directives` is no longer used

Answer (score 2):

If someone gets this error on unit testing with karma.

I was getting this error with Karma testing. I solve this by importing **FlexLayoutModule**

#### example

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@app-modules/material.module.ts';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ MaterialModule, FlexLayoutModule ],
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I hope someone helped with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`[style]="{'opacity': bigImgOpacity}`
this is the right way to pind style from ts to HTML
I try it in angular 17

Answer (score 0):

**Highly misleading error**. For Angular 16 I observe this error when Component A is referenced by Component B, but Component A hasn't been added to the module.

Missing dependency
[image]

Added Dependency

[image]