# Same component, different styles

Tags: angular

What is the best practice to set up and run one component and use it with different styles in different locations? (dynamic styles?)

Answer (score 7):

**Switch between different styles using :host-context()**

Switch by applying different (predefined classes or attributes)

```ts
:host-context(.class1) {
  background-color: red;
}

:host-context(.class2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```ts
<my-comp class="class1></my-comp> <!-- should be red -->
<my-comp class="class2></my-comp> <!-- should be blue -->
```

**Use global styles**

```ts
* /deep/ my-comp.class1 {
  background-color: red;
}

// or to style something inside the component
* /deep/ my-comp.class1 /*deep*/ div {
  border: solid 3px yellow;
}

* /deep/ my-comp.class2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**Use host-binding**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  host: {'[style.background-color]':'backgroundColor'}
})
class MyComponent {
  @Input() backgroundColor:string;
}
```

```ts
<my-comp background-color="red"></my-comp>
<my-comp background-color="red"></my-comp>
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36503655/217408 for an interesting "hack".

Comment: Yes, :host-context() is perfect for me. Thanks.

Comment: unpracticable when one need a whole stylesheet per theme, If you have thousands of classes and need like 10 themes...

Comment: I don't see how your comment and my answer are related.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `styleUrls`/`styles` options inside you Component metadata, that you would be use, when that component gets rendered on view. It would be good if you use `ViewEncasulation` as `Emulated`/`Native`(will shadow DOM).

I'd recommend to read up on [**this great article**](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/25/styling-angular-2-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best practice would be controlling the styles through properties(attributes) of the component.