# Can't bind to ngClass, ngModel since it isn't a known property of div only for production build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I am getting the following error while building the angular 11 project.

```
Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
<div class="list" [ngStyle]="{'max-height': maxheight + 'px'}">
```

Same error is coming for all templates.

For development build its working fine, but for prod getting those errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 Exception: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known native property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503654/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-ngstyle-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-proper)

Comment: Take a look for [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503654/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-ngstyle-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-proper)

Comment: i have checked almost all questions, nothing helped.
when i do `ng build --prod` then only getting those errors.

Comment: @SurajGupta could you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import CommonModule and FormsModule, even if it is a lazy-loaded module via SharedModule or directly

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  ...
})
```